# When creating a speech bubble with a specific shape in css, set the transparency after

Tags: html, css, background

[image]

I am trying to implement the above speech bubble shape with css. How should I set the transparency when the background of the body is gradient?

When set to transparent for the background of after, it is specified as the background of before. If so, should I change the order of after and before to implement it? help!

```css
.body {
        padding: 30px 0 20px 0 !important;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #E51D38,#C90E97);
    }

    .speech-bubble {
        text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 50px;
        margin: 1em auto 50px;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }

    .speech-bubble:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
        left: -22px;
        top: 0;
        width: 40px;
        border-bottom: 35px solid white;
        border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    }

    .speech-bubble:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index:3;
        left: -28px;
        top: -3px;
        height: 38px;
        width: 28px;
        background: lightgray;
        border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="speech-bubble">Hello, world.</div>
```

Comment: add your HTML please

Comment: I uploaded the html code in the body.

Comment: @Ugene this won't work. Using borders this way can only add stuff, not remove it. I can't see that this can be done with borders, have you considered using a clip-path instead, or a mask?

Comment: @Ugene I don't think so ut up to them to confirm. I think that is the problem that the inner curve is being made by a pseudo element blotting out the background, and this only works if the background is a constant color (I guess initially the example had a gray background) not a linear gradient.

Comment: @Ugene they want that gray bit to be transparent so you see the pink linear gradient below. This can't be done using this border method.

Comment: So, should I use an image?

Comment: I would use clip-path on the element as that would be responsive.

Comment: @AHaworth Something like this? "https://codepen.io/ugenetang/pen/bGWyaBO"

Comment: @Ugene That looks nie - I hadn't thought of box shadow.

Comment: @김세림 Take a look at the Pen might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a gradient coloration then simply control the width/height of the element:

```css
body {
  padding: 30px 0 20px 0 !important;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #E51D38, #C90E97);
}

.speech-bubble {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 1em auto 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.speech-bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:40px;
  top:0;
  left:-25px;
  background: radial-gradient(50% 100% at bottom left,#0000 98%,white);
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="speech-bubble">Hello, world.</div>
```